# How to sample discrete distribution conditional on factor within for if loop

Tags: r, for-loop, sample

I'm attempting to generate dummy data by sampling from a specific discrete distribution - conditional on the levels of a factor (so a different distribution for each factor level) and then wish to insert each random result into a new dataframe column in the row corresponding to the factor level. If you run the code below you will see that 'data$last' is empty. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've tried it without the loop as well, by setting replications to 100 for each level - however the distributions are incorrect.

```
#Create data frame with factor 
set.seed(1)
ID<-(1:200)
gender<-sample(x = c("Male","Female"), 200, replace = T, prob = c(0.5, 0.5))
data<-data.frame(ID,gender)

#Generate random response based on discrete distribution conditional on gender
data$last <- for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {if(data$gender=="Male") {
sample(x = c("Today","Yesterday"), 1, replace = T, prob = c(0.8, 0.2))
} else {
sample(x = c("Today","Yesterday"), 1, replace = T, prob = c(0.3, 0.7))
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rewrite your for-loop to assignate each data$last value inside the loop :

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  if(data$gender[i]=="Male") {
    data$last[i] = sample(x = c("Today","Yesterday"), 1, replace = T, prob = c(0.8, 0.2))
  } else {
    data$last[i] = sample(x = c("Today","Yesterday"), 1, replace = T, prob = c(0.3, 0.7))
  }
}
```

Or without for-loop :

```
data$last = ifelse(data$gender=="Male", 
               sample(x = c("Today","Yesterday"), length(data$gender[(data$gender=="Male")==TRUE]), replace = T, prob = c(0.8, 0.2)), 
               sample(x = c("Today","Yesterday"), length(data$gender[(data$gender!="Male")==TRUE]), replace = T, prob = c(0.3, 0.7)))
```

Comment: It is quite perplexing as the first version above generates almost identical distributions for both genders, and the second 'without for-loop', produces 100% today or yesterday depending on gender. Here is the subsequent code to view as table:  #Requirements
library(expss)
library(magrittr)
#Label and order
data$gender<-factor(data$gender,levels=c("Male","Female"))
data$gender<-as.labelled(data$gender)
#Create banner
banner = calc(data, list(total(),gender))
#Run table 
data %>%
tab_cells(last) %>%
tab_cols(banner) %>%
tab_stat_cpct() %>%
tab_pivot()

Comment: I let incorrectly fixed the sample size at 1, it is modified now.

Comment: Using your first version above with the loop, it works on the first run with 0.8, 0.2 for male and 0.3, 0.7 for female approximately. Strangely, if it is rerun again, it reverts to 0.3,0.7 distribution approx. for both genders.

Comment: Thanks I accept the first example as answer, but with proviso that 'data$gender<-as.labelled(data$gender)' is not run, as this is a peculiarity of expss package that creates a new class of labelled value which the 'if' control does not seem to recognise.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Generate random response based on discrete distribution conditional on gender
data$last <- sapply(1:nrow(data),function(i){if(data$gender[i]=="Male") {
  s =sample(x = c("Today","Yesterday"), 1, replace = T, prob = c(0.8, 0.2))
} else {
  s = sample(x = c("Today","Yesterday"), 1, replace = T, prob = c(0.3, 0.7))
}
  return(s)
})
```

Check how you didn't look for an specific `data$gender` but for the whole vector. Also, return the result using `return(s)`

Comment: I find it generates a distribution that is 80:20 approximately (today:yesterday) for both male and female, where specified probabilities in sample function are quite different for both genders.

Comment: Sorry, I used a different letter for `function(i)` and `data$gender[x]`. Should be working now!

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason it works first time and then if you repeat your code it reverts to the same problem. Using this code you can see: #Requirements 
library(expss) 
library(magrittr) 
#Label and order 
data$gender<-factor(data$gender,levels=c("Male","Female")) 
data$gender<-as.labelled(data$gender) 
#Create banner 
banner = calc(data, list(total(),gender)) 
#Run table 
data %>% 
tab_cells(last) %>% 
tab_cols(banner) %>% 
tab_stat_cpct() %>% 
tab_pivot()